# My script does not go to the next server

Tags: powershell, powershell-v3.0

I'm trying to retrieve eventlog (with certain conditions) from multiple servers. It only checks the first server and does not move onto the next one. What is wrong with it? I tried different scripts (This are my first scripts ever, I know they suck)

```
Clear-Host
$serverArray = "DC1PRISEAS1","DC2DRISEAS1","ATLAH1PRBUSOB01","ATLAH1PRECLHS01","DC2STGHYPFS1","DC2STGHYPFS2","DC2STGHYPRS1","DC2STGHYPRS2","DC2STGHYPHFM1"

foreach ($element in $serverArray) 
{

    Write-Output "$element"
    Get-Eventlog -Logname System -After (Get-Date).Adddays(-1) -ComputerName $element | Where {$_.entryType -Match "Error"}

}
```

Comment: It sure seems like it should work.  Are you getting any errors at all?  Are all the servers online and reachable?  Does `Get-Eventlog` work if you specify individual servers directly?

Comment: Consider rewriting as a workflow so you can leverage the parallel engine to speed up the process.

Comment: @Colyn1337 I agree this would be a great use case for a work flow, if and only if speed matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified you script does work, there is a long lag time between connections. You just need to let it run and be patient.